# Convert my simple webapp to a distributed system

Tags: javascript, node.js, distributed-system

I've made a very simple Twitter-like web app to teach myself how to work with React, and how to actually get something working in practice. I've deployed it on a digital ocean droplet and it works just fine.

Now, I am currently studying distributed systems and I've become very interested in them (i could see myself working with them after I graduate). So I figured how to make my app "distributed" by running it on several servers simultaneously and have clients connect to different ones based on some arbitrary criteria. Obviously, this is all very overkill for what my app does, this is purely out of interest and because it sounds like a challenge.

The problem is that I don't really know how to start. I guess I would have to set up some sort of redirection service/replica manager that clients connect to at first, before their requests are sent to the chosen replica?

Any hints/tips for starting out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to use a loadbalancer, check out NGINX with multiple upstream backends: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/ Otherwise you can think of running your app multiple times on different IPs and do dns round robin, if you don't want your loadbalancer to be the single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a load balancer like the one digital ocean has. If you want to create your own:
I would create a server which would act as the balancer end. This server would keep track of the other servers and redirect clients to them. All the requests would go to that server and it could pass them on with some kind of logic. For example, you could pass the requests in a circle, one to each server and from the start again. You could also account for the response time of each server and give weights to them.
You can find many tutorials in google too:
[How to Build a Load Balancer with Express](https://www.lunchbadger.com/build-load-balancer-express/)